# What is the difference between memorized object vs using delegate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, delegates, ruby-on-rails-5

I use serializer to render each `Order` object (which includes `User` information)

In my serializer I have:

```
delegate :user, to: object
delegate :email, :phone_number, :verified?, to: :user
```

I found that I can also use memorized helper, like this:

```
private

def user
  @user ||= object.user
end
```

Is that better practise? And what is the difference?

Comment: You can check the logs to see how many queries does it fire in each case. Lesser the better.

Comment: This `delegate: :user, to: object` looks like a syntax error.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh there's no syntax error - it works for me and it loads in similar time, but I found example with memorized helper so I try to understand difference

Comment: It does _not_ work for you, `:` after `delegate` is wrong :)

Comment: okey my fault ;D correctedthx

Comment: Can you print the server logs for both cases?

Comment: You have to point, that this is `ActiveModelSerializers` to be clear. We don't need server logs or whatever to guess that there is no difference in performance despite the way we choose. We got exactly same number of DB queries(N+1 w/o .includes). So, in this case delegate is preferred way. Private methods are needed when logic is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Using delegate is better because you need less code and it's easy to understanding.

If you will create user helper, you need call `user.email, user.phone_number, user.verified?` instead of call `email, phone_number, verified?` in your context when you use delegation.

Comment: You should not use something just because it is less code. Performance too is an important aspect of the application.

Comment: Often, code readability is more important than a minor performance gain.

Comment: Okey, so I understand here that if I join table in controller (`.include`) there is no difference in logs, so is better idea to use shorter, more readable code, but for future (no join before) I would use memorize object - better for performance

Comment: We must see the action of your controller to give the response to your question.
The best practice: you must not leave much logic in the controllers, you must move it into some services.